Can a mesh block grease pencil strokes?
I need advice on how to achieve the effect in this video at 1:25. Basically, the artist was able to take a mesh that had grease pencil strokes "attached" and then by creating a shader holdout on the mesh and adding a solidify modifier, create a "drawing" that turns in space.
I followed her instructions to the T, multiple, multiple times and I still end up with the attached, in that you can still see through the mesh holdout to the lines on the other side.
The order of operations, as in video are:

In 2D workspace(3d workspace I tried as well) add UV Sphere.

Add stroke with Stroke Placement set to Surface and Offset to 0.

In Shader, add Holdout to Material of Sphere.

Back in 2d workspace, Select All Transforms.

Add Solidify Modifier, change offset to 1 and deselect Camera icon.


After doing that, I don't get the effect shown in vidoe
Thank you so much for helping me not lose more sleep.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY0gjIttZRw



So all those explanations can be distilled to: the sphere is not blocking the grease pencil strokes, do I read that correctly?

Hi Gorodn, Thank you so much for your help! Yes, you absolutely got what my issue was. And yes it worked when I checked the Z data pass. I do have a follow up just want to make sure if I should ask here or edit my original question. Thanks!

It is preferred to deal with one topic per post. If the original issue is solved it is always better to post a new question with another problem.

I totally get it. But if what if it's a follow up to the previous question/issue? Thanks!

This site is full of follow up questions. Either it is similar so that it is rather an addition to the original question and you might edit it into this one... but then you risk that people who already saw this question will not take a second look and it moves further down in the list of questions. Or it is somehow connected to this but can stand on its own as question, then it will also be on top of the list when posted new. But I forgot my crystal ball, I have no idea what you want to ask next and how I would categorize it.

Thanks again for the helpful advice! I think I'll try a few more things on my own before asking again. Again, I'm very grateful for your time and expertise.
